# symfony > HWIOAuthBundle > cannot login with OAuth

Tags: oauth, symfony, hwioauthbundle

I'm facing a problem with #symfony2 and #HWIOAuthBundle.

**The case :**
I log in my local installation with the facebook connect button. it works well. I can see the set Cookie change value of the SESSION ID.

I try the same on a real webserver where everything else is working good but the facebook button do the redirection to the good page but i'm not logged in.

**What i See**
**I can see it match my route :**

> [2016-05-18 23:13:40] request.INFO: Matched route "facebook_login".

**i can see it correctly authenticate my user :**

> [2016-05-18 23:13:42] security.INFO: User has been authenticated
>   successfully. {"username":"toto"} []

**And after i can see this :**

> [2016-05-18 23:13:42] event.DEBUG: Notified event
>   "security.interactive_login" to listener
>   "FOS\UserBundle\EventListener\LastLoginListener::onSecurityInteractiveLogin".
>   [] [] [2016-05-18 23:13:42] event.DEBUG: Notified event
>   "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
>   [] [] [2016-05-18 23:13:42] event.DEBUG: Notified event
>   "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure".
>   [] [] [2016-05-18 23:13:42] event.DEBUG: Notified event
>   "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
>   [] [] [2016-05-18 23:13:42] event.DEBUG: Notified event
>   "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
>   [] [] [2016-05-18 23:13:42] event.DEBUG: Notified event
>   "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
>   [] [] [2016-05-18 23:13:42] event.DEBUG: Notified event
>   "kernel.request" to listener
>   "AppBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
>   [2016-05-18 23:13:42] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to
>   listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
>   [] [] [2016-05-18 23:13:42] event.DEBUG: Notified event
>   "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest".
>   [] [] [2016-05-18 23:13:42] event.DEBUG: Notified event
>   "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
>   [2016-05-18 23:13:42] event.DEBUG: Listener
>   "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest" stopped
>   propagation of the event "kernel.request". [] [] [2016-05-18 23:13:42]
>   event.DEBUG: Listener
>   "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest"
>   was not called for event "kernel.request". [] [] [2016-05-18 23:13:42]
>   security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. []
>   []

**difference between my local development plateform VS the webserver **
The only difference i see is that when the user is redirected, i have a set-cookies with a new SESSION ID and it works on local.

I have not the set cookie in my response on the web server.

I'm new on symfony. Maybe it's very easy but for the moment i'm blocked.

Thanks for your help,

Pierre.

Comment: I think post lacks the configuration sample

Comment: thanks it was a problem in the config file.

Comment: Can you copy your security.php file please ? I think there is bad configuration of firewall.